# Capturing the global event of center click of mouse using c#

Tags: c#

I want to capture the global event of center click of mouse using c#.

If the user clicks the center button or presses the scroll [both same], i want to
show a message box to the user.

How to do this?? provide me some ideas. I am new to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at this [code project article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/globalsystemhook.aspx).

Comment: @Pavel - beat me too it. I was going to recommend that article as well.